# Configure renovate bot to merge minor and patch updates automatically

Tags: github, renovate

On my GitHub repo I want to configure the renovate bot to automatically merge all minor (and smaller) updates automatically and to create PRs only for major updates. If I understand the doc correctly, my package rules should configure that behaviour:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "config:base",
    ":disableDependencyDashboard"
  ],
  "ignorePaths": [
    "Dockerfile",
    "package.json",
    "pnpm-lock.yaml"
  ],
  "assignees": [
    "McPringle"
  ],
  "reviewers": [
    "McPringle"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch", "pin", "digest"],
      "automerge": true
    },
    {
      "matchDepTypes": ["devDependencies"],
      "automerge": true
    }
  ]
}
```

But the renovate bot does not merge the minor updates. Still, everything comes as a PR, which I have to merge manually. This is an example:

```
-    <version>2.6.1</version>
+    <version>2.6.2</version>
```

This patch update should be merged automatically. Can someone please explain what I am understanding and doing wrong? Here you can find the GitHub repo I'm talking about including the renovate config file and the PR, which I have not merged now: https://github.com/komunumo/komunumo-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I am documenting my solution which I found with the help from the [Renovate discussion forum at GitHub](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate/discussions/13273):

1. In `renovate.json`, configure `packageRules` with `automerge` and activate `platformAutomerge`:

```json
{
  "extends": [
    "config:base"
  ],
  "packageRules": [
    {
      "matchUpdateTypes": ["minor", "patch", "pin", "digest"],
      "automerge": true
    },
    {
      "matchDepTypes": ["devDependencies"],
      "automerge": true
    }
  ],
  "platformAutomerge": true
}
```

2. In the GitHub repository settings, go to `Option` and activate at least `Allow auto-merge` and `Automatically delete head branches`:
   [image: GitHub option setting screenshot]
3. In the GitHub repository settings, go to `Branches` and add a branch protection rule for your `main` or `master` branch (whatever you are using). Activate `Require status checks to pass before merging` and `Require branches to be up to date before merging`. If GitHub tells you "No status checks found", just ignore that. Rules must be saved explicitly (scroll down to the "Save" button).
   [image: GitHub branch setting screenshot]

The next PR from the renovate bot should be merged automatically.

Comment: Did this cause "all" of your PRs to be automerged if they passed checks? Don't suddenly want features getting merged automatically as soon as someone creates a PR.

Comment: @Wobbley: Simple answer: no

Answer (score 2):

You should add `"automergeType": "branch"`. Ref: https://docs.renovatebot.com/noise-reduction/#branch-automerging